# Async in loop wait for completion before going on

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, loops, asynchronous

I have the following code. At first, I thought that this would run an asynctask in each iteration of the foreach loop. However, it's not working like that at all. getPageNumber() is being executed as many times as the foreach dictates but it's being executed all at once, it's not waiting for the completion of an iteration. I want it to wait until one iteration is completed to start another asynctask and not run them all at once. How should I code this? Maybe I should just implement this using another approach... Thank you very much.

```
string [] lang = {"all", "spanish"};

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in urlsDictionary)
    {
        var pageNumber = getPageNumber("http://" + entry.Value +     
            "&supportedlang=" + lang[i] + "&page=1");
        pageNumber.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            int totalPagesR = pageNumber.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Total pages found " + entry.Key + " : " +
                totalPagesR.ToString());

            var task = DoNavigationAsync("http://" + entry.Value + "&supportedlang" + lang[i] + 
                "&page=", totalPagesR, "<a class=\"search.*?href=\"/app/(.*?)/.*?<span class=\"title\">(.*?)</span>", "folder/name" + entry.Key + lang[i]);
            task.ContinueWith((t2) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " completed...");
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());                   
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`?

Comment: @B.K. Another loop, I wanted to do the whole foreach twice with one parameter changed.

Comment: Oups, that for loop should be i < 2. Yes, I've realized that today, otherwise it has no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than explicitly adding the continuations, which you could *technically* use to do what you want (through the use of a state machine that "remembers" where you are in the iteration between continuations) it's *much* easier to leverage `await` to handle the continuations for you:

```
string[] languages = { "all", "spanish" };

foreach (var language in languages)
{
    foreach (var entry in urlsDictionary)
    {
        var pageNumber = await getPageNumber("http://" + entry.Value +
            "&supportedlang=" + language + "&page=1");
        Console.WriteLine("Total pages found " + entry.Key + " : " + pageNumber);

        await DoNavigationAsync("http://" + entry.Value +
            "&supportedlang" + language + "&page=",
            pageNumber,
            "<a class=\"search.*?href=\"/app/(.*?)/.*?<span class=\"title\">(.*?)</span>",
            "folder/name" + entry.Key + language);

        Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " completed...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yours is a more complete answer. I'll delete mine for the sake of avoiding redundancy.

Comment: Thank you and also @Joao_Milasch, both answers were useful too. However, I could only mark one as an answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I also like your better - but I left continuations alone - as adding awaits was all it took to actually solve. Some folks like the encapsulation of ContinueWith - looks more like constructs in languages they're familiar with...say, like JavaScript

Comment: @Clay Your answer is the equivalent of sticking duct tape on a leaking boat.  It might technically work for a bit, but its a big mess and not really fixing the core problem at hand.  In my eyes its an irresponsible answer to the question as it demonstrates a lack of understanding of the core concepts.  It's not necessarily that `ContinueWith` is universally wrong or not useful, but, at least in your example, it's *entirely superfluous*.  You're adding a big giant mess to the code with a bunch of extra compile time and runtime work to *literally accomplish nothing*.

Comment: @Clay `await`ing the continuation, as you've done, is almost exactly like starting a new thread only to immediately wait on it to finish, instead of just running that code directly.  It's wasting time and effort purely for the sake of wasting time and effort.

Comment: @Servy, actually - it's just a copy of the question code with await.  I'm sorry if it's offensive.  Only trying to help.  I'll delete mine now that the votes dissolved :-)